# Magento 2 Schema post-updates

Tags: magento2, install-script

After adding a new module to Magento2 I need to enable it using

```
bin/magento module:enable Module_Name
```

then, I need to run the install scripts from the module using

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

While running this I see in the log these messages:

1. Schema creation/updates
2. Installing schema
3. Schema post-updates
4. Data install/update

1, 2 and 4 are clear. Actually 1 and 2 seam to be the same thing. Applying the schema delta. So it runs everything from `Setup/InstallSchema.php` (that needs to run)
4 installs data for the modules. So it runs everything from `Setup/InstallData.php`.

What does `Schema post-updates` mean, what it does and how can I use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea of post-updates is that module can trigger additional install AFTER other modules did their schema install/updates. In our module we would need to have Setup/Recurring::install() to enable it.

Let's say we are installing 3 modules at the same time, all 3 have install scripts, but only first one has post-update, execution will go as follows:

1. Module1/Setup/InstallSchema
2. Module2/Setup/InstallSchema
3. Module3/Setup/InstallSchema
4. Module1/Setup/Recurring

Only current example in Magento2 is Indexer/Setup/Recurring that, I think, checks if new indexer is registered with new module and writes its state into database.

One more thing, post-updates is triggered always, it will be executed on each setup:upgrade, even if update didn't happen.